# How to integrate CCavenue Payment gateway in my website?

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

Can anyone tell me the procedure for cc-avenue integration in my website?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Can you share ASP.NET  MVC Sample Project for this integration

Answer (score 3):

Go TO CCAvenue

- Obtain Merchant ID, Working Key, Integration Plugin
- Upload the Plugin to your Server
- Furnish it with details of Merchant ID, Working Key
  CC Avenue Integrated

Answer (score 1):

Goto CCAvenue website

```
1) create account in ccavenue.
2) you need to verify your mobile and email.
3) account will activate within one hour.
4) you will get username and password
5) CCAvenue's technical team will check you website ans content and based on that they will mail you.
6) there are some document you need to provide them like cancelled cheque, undertaking form etc.
7) after that they will give you marchant id based on your website
```